# C++ string with newlines and double quotes encoded as XML CDATA

Tags: javascript, c++, mysql, xml, xerces-c

I have a string (representing some Javascript code) with double quotes and newline characters like say:

```
<script src="mytest.js"></script>
<script>
   (function() { 
      var u = 'http://myserver.com/myapp.js';
      document.write('script src="' + u + '"></scr'+'ipt'>);
   })();
</script>
```

This string is stored in a MySQL database and I am using libzdb to read it into a C++ string in memory.

Now, I read this whole script string into a C++ std::string variable. As a result, the double quotes are escaped and the newlines are represented with \r\n characters. So the in-memory string looks like:

```
<script src=\"mytest.js\"></script>\r\n<script>(function() {\r\n var u =       'http://myserver.com/myapp.js';\r\n document.write('script scr=\"' + u + '\"></scr'+'ipt'>);\r\n})();\r\n</script>
```

Next, I put this in-memory string into a CDATA section using XERCES C++ library. And when the XML data is further serialized into a string, the encoded string (with escaped quotes and newline characters) appears in the XML data.

How can I ensure that the CDATA section in XML does not have escaped quotes and newline characters?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you read this Javascript code into C++ string? You *shouldn't* get any escape characters. The escape characters are not for data stored in memory; they are for you to use in your code to avoid misinterpreting strings by the compiler.

Comment: This javascript code is stored in the database and I read it into C++ using libzdb (See http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/).

Comment: Exactly what @Jaywalker said. If your debugger shows that a string contains `"\""`, then that string contains *one* character. That one character is a double quote character. It does not contain any backslash, that backslash only appears in the textual representation of that string. Same for all other escape sequences.

Comment: Yes, when I print this C++ string to a file, I do not see the escape characters or \r\n. However, it is when the data is converted to XML, the CDATA section has the escaped quotes and \r\n. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: What library/ code you are using to convert this into XML?

Comment: Sorry folks, as mentioned by ye all, the escape characters and \r\n are only seen on the debugger, but they do not actually form part of the string. Thanks for your help.